# Promises not rendering Events on FullCalendar Javascript JSON

Tags: jquery, json, events, fullcalendar

I know this topic might be boring already, but I cannot seem to find the answer to my problem. And what is happening is that I cannot render the events in the FullCalendar when I am using Promises. Am I using them incorrectly?

Please take a look to my code below,

```
$.getScript('http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js',function(){

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

function getData(){
    var prom = new Promise(function(fulfilled, rejected){
        $.ajax({
            url: "control.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "function=XML",
            success: function(response){
                fulfilled(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                rejected(error);
            }
        });

    });
    return prom;

}

getData().then(assignData,errorHandlingData);

function assignData(variable){
    $('#cal').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next,today',
            right: 'today,prev,next',
            center: 'title'},
        editable: false,
        events: variable,
        height: $(window).height() - 200
    });

    $('#source-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#cal").fullCalendar('render');
    });
}

function errorHandlingData(variable){
    alert('Error Handling the data', variable);
    console.log('Error Handling the data', variable);
}
});
```

if I place an alert() right after this assignData() declaration, I can see the data, but it doesn't gets assigned to the events, therefore they don't get rendered.

I would really appreciate your help on this topic.

Comment: What is purpose of setting `async:false` at `$.ajax()` options?

Comment: I have changed the code so many times that I did not realized the async was there. I beg your pardon.

Comment: Does removing `async:false` return expected result?

Comment: No it did not, I think that the problem is with the Promises declaration, but I do not know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: What is expected response from request? Can you reproduce issue at stacksnippets?

Comment: @LocustX did you solve this?

Comment: Hello @olefrank, no I havent been able to solve it yet. I will but I am waiting for a miracle

Comment: @olefrank check the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my own question, changed the code to something different.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.getScript('http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js',function(){

  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  $('#cal').fullCalendar({
      header: {
          left: 'prev,next,today',
          right: 'today,prev,next',
          center: 'title'},
      events: '/TRTalpha/main/control/feed.php',
      editable: false,
      height: $(window).height() - 200
  });

  $('#source-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $("#cal").fullCalendar('render');
  });


});
```

**PHP**

```
$result = $model->getAllReservationsUser($_SESSION['eNumber']);
echo json_encode($result);
```

**MySQL**

```
Select rs.idReserv as 'id', rs.date as 'start',
CONCAT(rt.name,', ',rt.time) as 'title' 
FROM reservation rs inner join routes rt on rs.fk_route = rt.id_route
WHERE eNum = penum;
```

I changed my stored procedure to retrieve the information with different headers, this way when I encode the data to JSON, will fit the standards of FullCalendar. I know this will consume resources, but changing the query in MySQL I can obtain data in a 6 months frame.